# Integrable function $f$ on $(\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N),\mu)$ and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

**Problem**

Let $(\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N),\mu)$ where $\mu(A)=card(A)$. Show that $f \in L^1(\mathbb N,\mu)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(n)|<\infty$, in which case $\int_X f d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$.

I am stuck on one implication. Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(n)|<\infty$. If $A_n=\{n\}$, then $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\mathcal X_{A_n}$. If I define $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\mathcal X_{A_k}$ then $\lim_n g_n=f$. I call $h=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(n)| \mathcal X_{A_n}$, then $$\int_X hd\mu=\sum_{n \geq 1}\int_X |f(n)| \mathcal X_{A_n}d\mu$$$$=\sum_{n \geq 1}|f(n)|\int_X \mathcal X_{A_n} d\mu$$$$=\sum_{n \geq 1}|f(n)|\mu(A_n)=\sum_{n \geq 1} |f(n)|<\infty$$

Note that $|g_n| \leq h \in L_1(\mathbb N, \mu)$ for all $n$, so $|f| \leq |h|$, which implies $f$ is integrable. By the dominated convergence theorem $$\int_X f d\mu=\lim_n \int_X \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\mathcal X_{A_k}d\mu$$$$=\sum_{k\geq 1} f(k)\int_X \mathcal X_{A_k}d\mu$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$$

I don't know what to do to prove the other implication, if $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^n |f(k)| \mathcal X_{A_k}$, where $A_k$ is the set I've already defined, then $g_n \nearrow g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(k)|X_{A_k}$, so by the monotone convergence theorem, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f(k)|=\int_X g d\mu$$$$=\lim_n \int_X g_nd\mu$$

I would like to affirm $\lim_n \int_X g_nd\mu<\infty$, I would appreciate suggestions to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assume that $f \in L^1(\mathbb N, \mu)$, i.e. $$\int_{\mathbb N} \vert f \vert \, \mathrm d\mu < \infty \; .$$ Now we set 
$$ f_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \vert f(k) \vert \chi_{\{k\}} \quad \text{for each $n \in \mathbb N^\times$} \; .$$
We observe that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N^\times$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \vert f \vert$. So by the Monotone Convergence Theorem we get 
$$ \int_{\mathbb N} \vert f \vert \, \mathrm d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb N} f_n \, \mathrm d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \vert f(k) \vert = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert f(k) \vert < \infty \; .$$

Comment: What a fool, I didn't realize $ \vert f \vert=g$, thanks!